# Not able to create a new ember app - Could not resolve dependency error

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm just trying to create a new app from scratch, but getting this error:

```
Command failed with exit code 1: npm install --loglevel error
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: ember-sample@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: ember-cli@4.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/ember-cli
npm ERR!   dev ember-cli@"~4.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer ember-cli@"~3.2.0" from ember-cli-dependency-checker@3.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/ember-cli-dependency-checker
npm ERR!   dev ember-cli-dependency-checker@"^3.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

These are the repro steps:

open command prompt in Win11.
install ember

```
npm install -g ember-cli
```

create app ember-sample

```
ember new ember-sample
```

and just after that I get the error above.

Could I be missing anything? I have already installed node v16.14.2, npm 8.5.0, ember-cli: 4.3.0
I was already taking a look on ember.js [official website](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/getting-started/quick-start/)

Comment: this was just released - might be a bug, can you try `npm install -g ember-cli@4.2.0`?

Comment: thank you, not sure why but I had to go back to version 3.2.0 to make it work. I had the same error with version 4.2.0

Comment: try `--skip-npm` at the end -- just ran this locally myself, and the issue is with the automated install-things-for-you behavior that `ember new` does -- the problem is that `ember-cli-dependency-checker` is asking for an invalid version of ember-cli, so once you get your new app setup with `--skip-npm`, delete that dependency, and then re-run npm install in your app.

Apologies for the disruption!!

Answer (score 3):

Actually Ember CLI is Compatible with NodeVersion 12. You might be using a later node versio like 14 or 16. My problem is solved when I downgraded to Node 12 lts

Answer (score 0):

A fix is on its way. You could follow what @NullVoxPopuli said in the comments.

https://github.com/quaertym/ember-cli-dependency-checker/issues/132